# Where is L.esri.query?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, esri

I have a website that is displaying a MapBox map, using Leaflet. One of the layers is generated from an Esri ArcGIS Rest interface, using Esri's Leaflet plugin: https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/

My current task is to allow the user to click on the map, and then to display information for nearby features in the ArcGIS layer. From reading the docs, Esri's [L.esri.query](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/tasks/query.html) object should be able to manage this.

My problem? L.esri.query is undefined.

Initially, I'd just been loading the v1.0 JS file:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/1.0.0/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
```

When that didn't work, I tried loading the v2.0 JS file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/2.0.0-beta.7/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
```

And when that didn't work, I included every plugin listed at https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/download/:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri.clustered-feature-layer/2.0.0-beta.1/esri-leaflet-clustered-feature-layer.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri.geocoder/2.0.2/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri.geocoder/2.0.2/esri-leaflet-geocoder.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri.renderers/2.0.1/esri-leaflet-renderers.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri.gp/2.0.2/esri-leaflet-gp.js"></script>
```

And still, nothing. So, the question, where is L.esri.query() defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be noted that `esri-leaflet.js` version 2.0.0-beta.7 seems to require Leaflet version 1.0.0.

See code in all [examples](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/).

With Leaflet 1.0.0, `L.esri.query` seems to work.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/17/

Comment: I've found that L.esri.Tasks.query() does exist - so I'm clearly getting an older version of esri-leaflet loaded.